# Split String in Java with on previous character

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string, which is a chained process call, and I need to get the individual processes in a list, so that I can then work on the individual processes.

For eg.

if I have

`'funca("hello world").funcb("this.is.sparta").funcc()'`

I want to get an arraylist that has

`['funca("hello world")' , 'funcb("this.is.sparta")' , 'funcc()']`

Now, I cannot split the string on '.' as the parameters being passed can also have the '.' character. I tried splitting on ').' but this ends up with a ugly looking split of

`['funca("hello world"' , 'funcb("this.is.sparta"' , 'funcc()']`

So basically what I need now is a way to split on ').', but split only on the associated '.'. Is this possible with the split function? Or should I get locations of all ').' and then manually split?

I'm unsure how to proceed. Pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Is `funca("this.(is).sparta").funcb()` correct/possible input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind in your regex:

```
String text = "funca(\"hello world\").funcb(\"this.is.sparta\").funcc()";
String[] split = text.split("(?<=\\))\\.");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

**Output:**

```
[funca("hello world"), funcb("this.is.sparta"), funcc()]
```

The regex `(?<=\))\.` matches a dot preceded by a `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really splitting the string on some character, but are identifying a pattern in a large string. So, instead of using `String#split()`, you should use `Matcher#find()` to find all the patterns that matches `func(arg1, arg2, ...)`. That pattern would be something like this:

```
\\w+\\([^)]*\\)
```

Code:

```
String str= "funca(\"hello world\").funcb(\"this.is.sparta\").funcc()";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\([^)]*\\)").matcher(str);

List<String> matchedFunction = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
  matchedFunction.add(matcher.group());
}

System.out.println(matchedFunction);
```

Comment: What is `func(arg, arg, arg)` about here?  I'm not seeing the relevance.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I'm sure `"hello world"` in `funca("hello world")` is an argument.. There can be multiple arguments like that..

Comment: Yes but the problem in the question is about dots not commas.  What does it matter if there are multiple args?

Comment: @CandiedOrange Problem in the question is neither about dots nor commas. It's about finding the strings that matches the pattern of a method call. Op was approaching the problem in wrong way by thinking of splitting the chained call.

Comment: Some of the dot's are what are called sequence points.  Others aren't.  He needs a way to tell them apart.